# AWS Lambda Function returns Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm stuck with my first attempt to run an AWS Lambda function taken from [1].

Once I invoke the Lambda Function from the Gateway, it displays the index.html page. However, when I enter the form parameters, it leads to this link:

https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?name=myname&location=loc

which contains just:

```
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

Here is the Lambda function:

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs';

const html = fs.readFileSync('index.html', { encoding: 'utf8' });

/**
 * Returns an HTML page containing an interactive Web-based tutorial.
 * Visit the function URL to see it and learn how to build with lambda.
 */
export const handler = async (event) => {
    let modifiedHTML = dynamicForm(html,event.queryStringParameters)
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        },
        body: modifiedHTML,
    };
    return response;
};
function dynamicForm(html,queryStringParameters){
    let formres = ''
    if(queryStringParameters){
            Object.values(queryStringParameters).forEach(val => {
                  formres =formres+val+' ';
            });
    }
    return html.replace('{formResults}','<h4>Form Submission: '+formres+'</h4>')
}
```

am I missing something in it?

Thanks

[1] https://serverlessland.com/getting-started/lambda/#step1

Comment: The ServerlessLand demo configured and invokes a Lambda Function URL but you seem to be invoking an API Gateway URL.

Comment: You need to set the apigateway path as `{proxy+}` to allow any path to work, as of now you might not configured this.